# android accent color fading in android kitkat

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

So i have buttons and layouts all over my app and they sometimes have the background color set to the accent color, which in my case is green...i'm testing the app and it sometimes fades the color of these views whether its a layout or button. by fading i mean i can still see the color green but its like there is a white layer on top of it and it makes the view almost invisible, and this happens sometimes all over the app once the view has the accent color as background and sometimes it shows the accent color normally when i run it, this only happens on kit-kat(4.4) not lollypop or marshmallow

here is a snippet of a linear layout with background color

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:gravity="end"
    android:id="@+id/bottom"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/close_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimary"
        android:text="Close"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="end"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/comments_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimary"
        android:text="Comments"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_gravity="end"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

http://geniusesng.com/images/first.png

and here is a button snippet

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:id="@+id/showSettingsBtn"
            android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimary"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"/>
```

this button shows not but sometimes its whitened out

[image]

any help will be appreciated as to why the fading occurs

Comment: post the screenshots

Comment: will post the images asap

Comment: what you added gives 404